# how to store contetnts of a several array in a matrix in C

Tags: vector, matrix, transfer

I am trying to store contents of different vectors in a matrix.

length of vectors are different and they are all strings. lets say:

A=["MXAA', "MXBB", "MXCC"]
B=["JJJ", "LKLKLKL"]

so the new matrix should look like the following:

C= [MXAA, MXBB, MXCC;JJJ, LKLKLKL, 0]

is the a way to do that in C?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an array of pointers to pointer to the element type (which in your case is a pointer to `char`).

The problem you need to consider is that every array is different size; so I suggest you store the size of the arrays, or you will quickly end up running over the bounds of an array. This sounds a bit like a custom type.

```
typedef {
  int n;
  char **strArr;
} stringArray;

stringArray *str2d;

str2d = (stringArray*) malloc(2*sizeof(stringArray));
str2d[0].n=3;
str2d[0].strArr = (char**)malloc(3*sizeof(char*));
str2d[0].strArr[0] = "MXAA";
str2d[0].strArr[1] = "MXBB";
str2d[0].strArr[2] = "MXCC";
str2d[1].n = 2;
str2d[1].strArr = (char**)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
str2d[1].strArr[0] = "JJJ";
str2d[1].strArr[1] = "LKLKLKL";
```

If you want to access an element you use similar addressing - but check that you stay within bounds!

I deliberately did this in very explicit steps, hoping this makes the principle clear. There are better ways to do this but they are more obscure (or not "standard C")